# How to change the specific values within a dictionary of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

This is the worst blocker that I have ever had attempting to learn Python.  I spent about 10 hours on this one and could really use help.

I want to have dictionaries hold lists in python and then access and change a specific value in those lists.  When I do this the way that seems logical to me and access a key then list value, it actually replaces other key's list values.

If I just assign 100 to the key XList it prints 100 for both XList and YList.  Why does assigning to one key effect the other???

And if I uncomment the assignment to YList it prints 254 for both.  Why can't I assign itemized values to keys and lists like this?  How can I assign specific values to lists within dictionaries and access the main lists via keys??  Why does what seems like changing just one keys list value change both key's lists???

```py
testDictKeys= ['XList', 'YList', 'ZList']

testDict = dict.fromkeys(['XList', 'YList', 'ZList'])

noneFillerList = [None] * 30



 #Now fill all the columns and row of the dictionary with zeros

for x in range(0,2):            
    testDict[testDictKeys[x]] = noneFillerList 



for x in range(0, 29):  
 
    testDict['XList'][x]=100

    #testDict['YList'][x]=254
    
print (testDict['XList'][0])
print (testDict['YList'][0])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you only create one list and assign every dictionary to contain it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only create one list and assign every dictionary to contain it. To fix the problem, be sure to create a new list to add to each dictionary.

Comment: I see.  My real code has 49 lists within the dictionary.  So I was thinking that I would fill all of the keys with the same blanks list until actually assigning values.  But instead.  I need 49 different "blanks" lists it sounds like.  All of the 49 lists have the same number of elements.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the fundamental misunderstanding of what dictionaries are or how they work.  You were 100% right.  Now I need to find a way to iterate this kind of assignment with loops.  It would be nice to define keys and corresponding lists from one name set.

Comment: @user2224727 This is has nothing to do with dictionaries. Lists are objects and when you assign `x = []`, you have a **reference** to the list object, not a copy of it.

Comment: @user2224727 The way you are using loops and a list of keys is just fine. The problem is how you assign the same list to each key. You need to create a new list each time the loop iterates rather than just creating one list before the loop starts.